# Logs for WP CLI

Tags: wp-cli

I am running a WP CLI script to regenerate images,
`seq 192000 194000 | xargs wp media regenerate —only-missing`

and i got errors, example:
`Warning: Can’t find “margot-fox-pope-francis-post” (ID 204823).`

there is anyway to save logs, so i can know which media file is not generated?

I tried this ssh command

`seq 192000 194000 | xargs wp media regenerate —only-missing | tee -a /home/site/public_html/export.txt`

but this command save only the success IDs, i need to log the failed ID
do you have any advice ?

Answer (score 0):

When you are ready to start recording a log file, type:

`script screen.log`

Now, until you stop the script, all input and output in the Terminal will be stored in screen.log. When you are done, just type:

`exit`

Source: [Ubuntu Guide - How To Log Terminal Commands](http://ubuntuguide.net/how-to-log-terminal-commands-and-outputs-in-ubuntu)